# how to increment a specific number in a csv file

Tags: substitute

I am very new to vim, and I have a csv file with this format :

```
"1006","text:xxx"
"2007","text:xxx"
"3008","text:xxx"
"4009","text:xxx"
"5001","text:xxx"
```

every "xxx" is replaced by an increment+1 of numbers at the start of each line. 
athe result should be like this:

```
"1006","text:1007"
"2007","text:2008"
"3008","text:3009"
"4009","text:4010"
"5001","text:5002"
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could use a substitution command like this one:

```
:%s/"\(\d\+\).*:\zs.\+\ze"/\=submatch(1)+1
```

The command can be decomposed in these several parts:

- `%` is the range of lines you want to apply the command to. `%` is all the lines in the buffer, check [`:h :range`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/cmdline.txt.html#%3Arange) for more options
- `s/ [...] / [...]` is the substitution which will replace the first part by a second one
- `"\(\d\+\).*:\zs.\+\ze"` This is the part used to match the text you want to act on, several things are going on here:

  - `"` is the first litteral `"` before the number you want to increment
  - `\d\+` is the number you will need to increment
  - the number is surrounded by `\( ... \)` to tell vim that we should capture this value to reuse it later on
  - `.*:` are all the characters between the end of your number and the `xxx` you'll need to replace
  - `\zs ... \ze` are used to say to vim that the part we actually want to change is between these two markers see [`:h /\zs`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/pattern.txt.html#%2f%5czs) and [`:h /\ze`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/pattern.txt.html#%2f%5cze)
  - `.\+` inside the `\zs ... \ze`  is are all the characters we want to replace (your `xxx`)
- `\=submatch(1)+1` is the second part of the command: what we will replace our text with

  - `\=` indicates that we will replace with the result of the evaluated expression following on. See [`:h sub-replace-expression`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/change.txt.html#sub-replace-expression)
  - `submatch(1)` is used to get the value of the captured string in the first part. [`:h /\=`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/pattern.txt.html#%2f%5c%3d)
  - and finally `+1` is used to increment the value

Comment: Just want to add that if you want to divide the captured number by some value, you may want to change the substitute delimiter to another character, for example, `#`, to avoid a clash with division character `/`.

Answer (score 5):

You can do this with a macro. Start by placing your cursor at the very start of the file <kbd>g</kbd><kbd>g</kbd> and then type the following:

<kbd>q</kbd><kbd>q</kbd><kbd>y</kbd><kbd>i</kbd><kbd>"</kbd><kbd>2</kbd><kbd>f</kbd><kbd>x</kbd><kbd>v</kbd><kbd>i</kbd><kbd>w</kbd><kbd>p</kbd><kbd>Ctrl-A</kbd><kbd>q</kbd>

This records a macro that will update a single line in the way you require. Then undo your changes <kbd>u</kbd><kbd>u</kbd> and play the macro on every line of the file by entering the command:

```
:%norm @q
```

How the macro works:

- <kbd>q</kbd><kbd>q</kbd> Start recording a macro into register `"q`.
- <kbd>y</kbd><kbd>i</kbd><kbd>"</kbd> Yank the contents of the next double-quoted string on the line.
- <kbd>2</kbd><kbd>f</kbd><kbd>x</kbd> Jump to the second `x` after the cursor.
- <kbd>v</kbd><kbd>i</kbd><kbd>w</kbd> Visually select the word `xxx`.
- <kbd>p</kbd> Replace the visual selection with the yanked text.
- <kbd>Ctrl-A</kbd> Increment the number.
- <kbd>q</kbd> Stop recording.